# Organize subgroup strings (text)

Tags: r, string, text, aggregate

I am trying to convert something like this `df` format:

```
df <- data.frame(first = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c"), 
  words =c("about", "among", "blue", "but", "both", "cat"))

df
  first words
1     a about
2     a among
3     b  blue
4     b   but
5     b  both
6     c   cat
```

into the following format:

```
df1
  first           words
1     a    about, among
2     b blue, but, both
3     c             cat
>
```

I have tried

```
aggregate(words ~ first, data = df, FUN = list)

  first   words
1     a    1, 2
2     b 3, 5, 4
3     c       6
```

and `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(first) %>% 
  group_rows()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: What about those didn't work?

Comment: It did not give the format I wanted with `words` (not `number`)

Comment: if you set the argument `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` in the data.frame, your first code (`aggregate(words ~ first, data = df, FUN = list)`) would work.

Comment: @B.ChristianKamgang You are absolutely right! I should have check that. I thought it was default. Many thanks!

Comment: @B.ChristianKamgang, please add as answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(first = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c"), 
  words =c("about", "among", "blue", "but", "both", "cat"))

df <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, toString), by = first]

df
#    first           words
# 1:     a    about, among
# 2:     b blue, but, both
# 3:     c             cat

# convert back to a data.frame if you want
setDF(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`, after the `group_by` use `summarise` to either `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(first) %>%
  summarise(words = toString(words))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  first words          
#  <fct> <chr>          
#1 a     about, among   
#2 b     blue, but, both
#3 c     cat
```

or keep it as a `list` column

```
df %>%
  group_by(first) %>%
  summarise(words = list(words))
```

Comment: Neat! I really like this. Thanks a lot.